# Why is FromJsonOverwrite not converting file data to my class object?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to deserialize my Json file to a Monobehavior class (my GameData class, which holds things like health, movement speed, etc.). Here's my code:

```
private string _filePath;
private static DataService _instance;

public DataService Instance
{
    get { return _instance; }
}

private GameData _gameData;

private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    if (_instance == null)
    {
        _instance = new DataService();
    }
    if (_gameData == null)
    {
        _gameData = new GameData(1);
    }
}

public void LoadGameData(GameData gameData)
{
    _filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, gameData.FileName);
    string json;
    if (File.Exists(_filePath))
    {
        json = File.ReadAllText(_filePath);
        _gameData = JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json,gameData);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("File missing.");
    }
}

public void SaveGameData(GameData gameData)
{
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(_gameData);
    _filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, gameData.FileName);
    if (File.Exists(_filePath))
    {
        File.Create(_filePath).Dispose();
    }
    File.WriteAllText(_filePath,json);
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type void to GameData.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I solve this?

If the solution is to put my data in a class that does not derive from MonoBehavior, how can I access these fields from my game?

Comment: From documentation `void JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(...)`... It does return nothing, so what do you expect?

Comment: Reading the API and examples solves most of the questions ...  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error, because 'FromJsonOverwrite' is Void, it does not return anything. Update your code to:

```cs
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, _gameData);
```